# How to use variables within a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have this code:

```
    foreach ($row as $result) {
    if (empty($row[28])) {
        $string28 = '';
    } else {
        $string28 = '<div class="add_img">
                       <h1>Connexion</h1>
                       <img src="images/' . $row[28] . '.jpeg">
                     </div>';
    }
}


foreach ($row as $result) {
    if (empty($row[30])) {
        $string30 = '';
    } else {
        $string30 = '<div class="add_img">
                      <h1>Fixation</h1>
                      <img src="images/' . $row[30] . '.jpeg">
                     </div>';
    }
}

foreach ($row as $result) {
    if (empty($row[31])) {
        $string31 = '';
    } else {
        $string31 = '<div class="add_img">
                       <h1>Schéma</h1>
                       <img src="images/' . $row[31] . '.jpeg">
                     </div>';
    }
}

$applications = array($string28, $string30, $string31);
if (empty($applications)) {
    $vide = "<h1>Pas D'Application Pour Ce Produit</h1>";
}
```

What I want to say here is: if all the variables are empty then show me this:

> ## Pas D'Application Pour Ce Produit
>
> (Translated: No application for this product)

---

**But When I use the print_r function it tells to me that the array has no data to deal with.

Please I need Help.

And Thanks to all in advanced**

Comment: Where are you using print_r. Empty function checks if the array is empty, not each individual variable

Comment: So How can I use it for all the variables together?

Comment: loop thorugh them and check individually if they are empty

Comment: Loop through the array like your are and check the array values using empty() or isset().  isset() will actually tell you if such a variable has even been initialized and is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing your rows correctly in your foreach loops.  When using foreach($row as $result) you need to refer to the array element as $result, not row.  If you need to identify a specify array key you can specify that by using foreach($row as $key => $result).

For example, in your first loop you should use this:

```
$string28 = '';  //Initialize your variable so can be used after the foreach loop exits
foreach ($row as $key => $result) {
    if($key == 28 && empty($result[$key]) {
        $string28 = '';
    } else {
        $string28 = '<div class="add_img"><h1>Connexion</h1><img src="images/'.$result[$key].'.jpeg">
    }
}
```

Repeat for the other loops in your script.

**EDIT**

Yes, you can setup one foreach loop that will go through all your variables and create variables for you.  Based on your question, if you don't have any apps an error message shows.  What you may wish to do is simply set a flag based on that criteria.  You could do do this like so:

```
$noApps = true;
$applications = array();
foreach($row as $key => $result) {
    if(isset($result[$key]) && empty($result[$key])) {
       $applications[$key] = '<div class="add_img"><h1>Connexion</h1><img src="images/'.$result[$key].'.jpeg'>;
    $noApps = false;
    }
}

if($noApps) {
    echo "<h1>Pas D'Application Pour Ce Produit</h1>";
} else {    
    print_r($applications);  //For viewing/debugging purposes
}
```

Comment: Set your $stringXX variables outside of the foreach loops.  I think you have a scope issue going on because the variables initialize (and die) inside the foreach loops.  I've edited my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: What needs to be reviewed?  Please elaborate.

Comment: Can I use one foreach loop to all the varialbs because I have 34 Variable?

Answer (score 1):

Your `foreach` loops is wrong. You are using the whole array instead of the elements as is used within a `foreach` loop.

You have used

```
foreach ($row as $result) {
    //You are doing something with $row
}
```

Instead correct usage is

```
foreach ($row as $result) {
    //Do something with $result
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your design looks bad. You are essentially repeating the **same functionality 3 times**. 
Your while loops don't work because you're using `$row` in them, instead of the `$result` variable.
The second point is, The `$string28, $string30, $string31` are created as local variables within the if conditions you have written in the `while loops`. Once the control exits the `"if"` loops these variables are nothing. To solve this problem, try initializing these to empty data like`$string28 =""` at the beginning point of your code.

However, I would recommend you to look at the structure of your code first.